# MySQL - Selecionar colunas de um subselect dinâmico

Tags: mysql

Dúvida: Como selecionar e somar campos dinâmicos?

Tenho uma consulta dinâmica:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT @TotalSpendMensal
     ) AS t
```

O resultado da variável @TotalSpendMensal é dinâmico, ou seja, returna por exemplo "JAN/2015", "FEV/2015" ou mais meses juntamente com seus valores. Retornando desta forma:

```
CentroCusto| JAN/2015 | FEV/2015 |...
CC1000     | 100.00   | 200.00   |...
CC2000     | 320.30   | 500.50   |...
```

Preciso que neste primeiro select retorne um total agrupado, ficando assim:

```
CentroCusto| JAN/2015 | FEV/2015 |...
TOTAL      | 420.30   | 700.50   |...
```

O problema é que, dinamicamente, não estou conseguindo selecionar os campos individualmente, para assim fazer o somatório.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Declaração do `@TotalSpendMensal`?

Comment: Não, @TotalSpendMensal se trata de um resultado de um statement dinâmico.

Comment: Acho que a única solução será fazer dessa query outra query dinâmica também.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode criar alias padronizados (A,B,C,etc...) para as colunas a serem totalizadas em  @TotalSpendMensal

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT 'MAR/2015' as A, 'ABR/2015' as B FROM @TotalSpendMensal
     ) AS t
```

e depois formatar conforme desejado

```
SELECT SUM(A) as 'MAR/2015', SUM(B) as 'ABR/2015'
FROM (
      SELECT 'MAR/2015' as A, 'ABR/2015' as B FROM @TotalSpendMensal
     ) AS t
```